# Artifactory Update Error - Migration checksum mismatch for migration 7.25

Tags: artifactory

I'm currently a "little" behind on the Artifactory version, currently running 7.27.10.
Now I was planning to update to first to 7.77.3 and after that failed to 7.49.8

On a testsystem I previously did the update from 7.27.10 to 7.49.8 and now to 7.77.3.
No issues here.

Systems are running with the docker-compose setup with nginx and an Oracle DB.

Now when I try to update the system I get a message like this:
"Validate failed: Migration checksum mismatch for migration 7.25"

For the update to 7.49.8 it is:
`artifactory  | 2024-03-25T13:04:22.296Z [jfac ] [INFO ] [6a07a0a3a7928417] [.s.d.u.AccessJdbcHelperImpl:73] [Catalina-utility-1  ] - Repairing and retrying migration due to checksum mismatch on access_db_check primary key. Migration name: V7_25__DbCheck.sql. Message: Validate failed: Migration checksum mismatch for migration 7.25`

for the update to 7.77.3 it is:
`artifactory  | 2024-03-22T10:45:33.879Z [jfac ] [ERROR] [9006ac52bf7a8528] [.s.d.u.AccessJdbcHelperImpl:73] [Catalina-utility-1  ] - Could not initialize database: artifactory  | org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException: Validate failed: Migration checksum mismatch for migration 7.25 artifactory  | -> Applied to database : -95149065 artifactory  | -> Resolved locally    : 2047900913`

Result is that the access component (jfac) never starts and system is always trying to connect and never finishes startup.

So far I tried to first install 7.77.3.
As that didn't work I tried 7.49.8.

It looks a little different but it seems to be essentialy the same error message.

I'm not sure what the next steps could be.
I've tried to find the sql-migration scripts to get an idea of what is being done, but I can't find it.

So any tipps would be greatly appreciated

Thanks in advance
Christoph

Answer (score 0):

so in my case these steps seem to help

1.) Fix index error: alter table "ARTIFACTORY"."MD_TASKS" disable  constraint "MD_TASKS_PK"

2.) It was not possible to update directly from 7.27.10 to 7.77.3; that resulted in the same error. So update was done from 7.27.10 -> 7.49.8 -> 7.77.3